# Nested ngFor with two-way data binding Angular2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ngfor, angular2-ngmodel

I try to make a table of input fields with help of nested ngFor with two-way data binding. I almost achieved this, but something with two-way data binding is wrong and I can't find a problem.

So, this is what I want to have - I want to be able type each letter of word in.

[image: My examle table with inputs fieleds]

I have this table, and I am able to type in, but if I type in first cell, the same value appears in second, if I type in third, value appears also in 4th and 5th...
And I can't understand why, I guess the problem is with this line

```
<input maxlength="1" size='5' name="{{i}}{{j}}" [(ngModel)]="helper[i][j]" [id]="j"/>
```

Could you please tell me, how could I fix this one?
Here is my plunker, it works, but with this mistake, that I described above...
[My plunker is here](https://plnkr.co/edit/fAiw8sLczfHqzdftNlIo?p=preview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `*ngFor`, you should try to avoid accessing directly the arrays you are iterating on, like with `[(ngModel)]="helper[i][j]"`.

Generally, you should try to always works with full object and dot(.) notation when using data binding.

In your case, just replace the raw array `['','','','','']` by an array of objects `[value: '', value: '', value: '', value: '', value: '']` and bind it directly.

```
<td *ngFor="let item2 of helper[i]; let j = index;">
    <input maxlength="1" size='5' name="{{i}}{{j}}" [(ngModel)]="item2.value" [id]="j"/>
</td>
```

I have updated your [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/6kBHSvyMl46Bzu2qWQwf?p=preview)